# Make a dropdown filter on a webpage that can read a .csv file and populate the dropdown menu

Tags: html, jquery, css, node.js

**A little context:** I work in a totally different department from web development but my current project needs me to make a webpage. I'm absolutely new to web development and have only a basic idea of HTML and CSS.

**What needs to be done?**: I made a webpage and I need to place a drop-down filter in the webpage which should be populated by the data from only one column in a .csv file that's stored locally in the PC. **The column will have duplicate records but I need only distinct records to be shown in the drop-down filter.**

A little research led me to realizing that I need to create an API using node.js. I have no exposure to node.js, let alone creating APIs. I'm hoping someone must have done this before and I'd be grateful if someone could tell me where and how do I get started on how to do this.

Comment: Privacy reasons

Comment: I rolled back your post. Please don't vandalize your post, people took effort to answer it. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153118/686592

Comment: "Privacy reasons" doesn't really apply - anyone can see whatever was removed by looking at the edit history. If you posted something you shouldn't have, you'll need to flag your question for removal by a mod.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is a good way to solve this. Generally, it might be good to start off by reading an [introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/).

Actually, most of the things you'll need might already be answered on Stack Overflow, so here's just a quick outline:

First off all, you will need to open up your csv using the included [file-system module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

Once you've got the csv as an array, turn that one column into an array:

```
csv.split('\n').map(v => v[ columnNumber ]);
```

[Then you dedupe that array.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array)

The last thing is to dynamically generate the dropdown, which is quite straight-forward - just use some for-loop, but figure that out yourself. To include it into the frontend, for example put the whole frontend's html into an external file and include a placeholder (like `{dropdown}`), fetch it with `fs`, an then replace the placeholder:

```
webAppString.replace('{dropdown}', generatedDropdownHtml);
```

Comment: Note that lists start with index 0. The second column therefore has index 1.